# How to identify if __iter__ is called by dict or list?

Tags: python

What I understand is `__iter__` method makes an object iterable. If it yields a pair, it produces a dictionary if called with `dict`. Now, if I want to create
class that creates a list of values if called with `list` and creates a dict if
called with `dict`, how to do that?

Let say the class is this:

```
class Container(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.pairs = [
           ('key1', 'val1'),
           ('key2', 'val2'),
        ]

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.pairs[idx][1]  # return value only

    def __iter__(self):
        for key, val in self.pairs:
            yield key, val
```

Now, if I use `list` or `dict`, I got:

```
data = Container()
list(data)  # [('key1', 'val1'), ('key2', 'val2')]
dict(data)  # {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}
```

What I want (with `list`) is:

```
list(data)  # ['val1', 'val2']
```

without keys.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: It's possible, but probably a terrible idea. Why can't you just have two functions? It'd be clearer, portable, and easier to implement. Dictionaries have `.items()`, `.keys()`, and `.values()`

Comment: That'd be horribly surprising to anyone using your class. I advise not trying to do that.

Comment: your way of thinking is actually dangerous - so the best advice is to give a step back and rethink what you actually need in the future: it is not part of the structured programming paradigm to a called function to "know" where it was called from, an change magically its behavior according to that. It would even Be possible in Python, but the resulting code would be unfit for production - as not only lists and dicts constructors consume iterables - and that is only one of the problems.

Comment: Its impossible. You may have some luck looking backwards on the stack for the calling object but that doesn't account for many use cases. `dict` verses `{...}` verses intervening functions such as `zip`. But an object isn't told the type of object that is creating it.

Comment: Ah, I see. it's my way of thinking that is wrong. I should redesign my code then. Thanks, anyway

Comment: @jsbueno If you don't mind, I think you should post an answer to tell it's impossible and not a good Idea. It maybe useful for future reader to this question.

Comment: I had a full answer - then I realized that I had misread the full answer - then I deleted it and copied the comment above from there.. Anyway, teh accepted answer starts with "That is a terrible idea" - so that is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a terrible idea! But you can try reading the calling line to see if the explicit `list` constructor was calling using the `inspect` module. Note that this only works when the `list` constructor is called and will probably produce unexpected results when the regex matches something it wasn't intended to match.

```
import inspect, re

class Container(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.pairs = [
            ('key1', 'val1'),
            ('key2', 'val2'),
        ]

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.pairs[idx][1]  # return value only

    def __iter__(self):
        line = inspect.stack()[1][4][0]
        # print list(Container())

        list_mode = re.match('^.*?list\(.*?\).*$', line) is not None

        for key, val in self.pairs:
            if list_mode:
                yield val
            else:
                yield key, val

print list(Container()) # ['val1', 'val2']
```

Comment: @Bagol: Please not that It is strongly advised that this code is not used in production.  Even Jared starts with "it is a terrible idea". It is fun code to play around with, and post here, that I agree. But to startwith if the one running the program does not have the .py file (programs can be run just with the pyc files) this would fail - as would, I think if inside a zipped egg file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to do it manually with something like a list comprehension

```
[v for k, v in data]
```

Comment: You probably want `[v for k,v in data]`.

Comment: But the answer to the question is you can't do it.

Comment: So, the answer is impossible and the best thing I can do is using list comprehension then

Comment: *this* is the "one and obvious way to do" what the O.P. wants.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't specifically what you want to do, but I'm not sure that what you want to do is that necessary. Let me know if it is-- though I'm not sure it's possible. In the meantime:

`list_data = [val for key,val in list(data)]`

Also what Blender said. That was really my first inclination, but I tried to stick more to what you were asking. Something like this:

```
def to_list(self):
    return [val for key,val in self.pairs]
```